# Can't override jquery mobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

if i specify `data-role="page"` on a div it adds a `element.style min-height`. I only need it to be on a specific height because on android emulator it overflows. I've tried adding a `!important` on the css side but still nothing works. help?

Comment: Show some code, `!important` should work if used correctly.

Comment: <div id="container" data-role="page"></div> // on css #container{ min-height: 0 !important; } this doesn't work. even if putting it inline.

Comment: Is the `min-height` being added by JavaScript? That would override any CSS declarations (including those with `!important`). You could perhaps attach an event to change it back once the page has finished loading (I don't know the specifics of how to accomplish this for jQuery Mobile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had these issues before, and I know this probably isn't the best way to fix it but it has worked for me in the past. Set the style in the div property.

```
<div data-role="page" style="min-height: 0;">
```

Comment: it didn't worked. when i look at firebug still it is set to 685px. based on what i've read jquery mobile is dynamically setting this depending on the width and height of the page. i just would like to be able to get rid of that and set it on my own terms for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old but in case anyone is wondering how to do this...
Use javascript to override the min-height style on the page
I set my min-height to the window height.

```
$( "#mypanelright" ).on( "panelopen", function( event, ui ) {
    var window_height = $(window).height();
    var thestyle = 'min-height:' + window_height + 'px';
    $("div:jqmData(role='page')").attr('style', thestyle);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the resize function and prevent the propagation of the event:

```
$(window).on("resize", function (event) {
    // Make your stuff with the page height:
    // $.mobile.activePage.css("min-height", "999px");
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```